# Skoda fault codes / Low Turbo boost

Tags: skoda

I have a Skoda Octavia Mk2 2008 model, 1.9TDI Diesel, Manual. (Here in India its known as "**Skoda Laura**" type 1)

Recently I had this problem of my clutch slipping so I replaced the Flywheel+Clutch plate+pressure plate(Clutch Assembly) of SACHS.
After that
1. I got my EGR Value cleaned(by removing the throttle body and cleaning it with carburetor spray and some liquid I am not sure what they used but now it's like new and shiny.
2. Removed the MAF sensor and got it cleaned with some spray as little dust was accumulated in it(carburetor spray i believe)

My pickup has significantly increased like a new car. However, I have noticed the TURBO is not kicking in as it used to around 1500-2000 RPMs. I have to keep on accelerating for the speed to go up (above 8 l/100km)

I used a VAG409.1 OBD2 II Interface USB Diagnostic Cable Auto Car Scanner for Audi/VW installed VAG-COM Release 409-1 and was successfully able to do an AUTO-SCAN.

Here are the scan results.

[QUOTE]
VAG-COM Version: Release 409.1-US

Chassis Type: 1Z - Skoda Octavia II
Scan: 01,02,03,08,09,15,16,17,19,25,37,3D,42,44,46,52,55,56,62,69,72,76,77,7D

---

Address 01: Engine
Controller: 03G 906 016 DJ
Component: R4 1,9L EDC G000SG 6250
Coding: 0050071
Shop #: WSC 73430
8 Faults Found:
18000 - Altitude Sensor / Boost Pressure Sensor: Implausible Correlation
P1592 - 000 - - - Intermittent
16497 - Shareware Version. To Decode all DTCs
P0113 - 000 - Please Register/Activate - Intermittent
16622 - Shareware Version. To Decode all DTCs
P0238 - 000 - Please Register/Activate - Intermittent
18057 - Powertrain Data Bus: Missing Message from ABS Controller
P1649 - 000 - -
18617 - Shareware Version. To Decode all DTCs
P2185 - 000 - Please Register/Activate - Intermittent
16567 - Shareware Version. To Decode all DTCs
P0183 - 000 - Please Register/Activate
16502 - Engine Coolant Temp. Sensor (G62): Signal too High
P0118 - 000 - -
16486 - Shareware Version. To Decode all DTCs
P0102 - 000 - Please Register/Activate
Readiness: N/A

---

Skipping Address 15-Airbags

End --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[/QUOTE]

The version of VAG-COM is asking me to register/activate so I will post below the Error code and Fault.

**P1592** Altitude Sensor / Boost Pressure Sensor: Implausible Correlation

**P0113** Intake air temperature (IAT) sensor -high input

**P0238** Turbocharger/Supercharger Boost Sensor A Circuit High Input

**P2185** Engine Coolant Temperature Sensor 2 Circuit High

**P0183** Fuel Temperature Sensor Circuit High Input

**P0118** Engine coolant temperature (ECT) sensor -high input

**P0102** Mass Air Flow (MAF) Circuit Low Input

Though my pick up is very good since the clutch is new I am not enjoying the ride as no Boost in Turbo, have to REV more to match the speed every time.

Do I need to change the sensors or any cleaning or refitting/reconnecting the sensors might help? Also what possible damages I have to suffer if I continue riding with the errors.

Thank you in Advance for all possible solutions.